# Can't spark-submit jar file from hdfs on remote machine

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, spark-submit

I'm trying to connect to my remote cluster using `spark-submit` and run a jar file that I've put on hdfs.

I have the following property in my `$SPARK_HOME/libexec/conf/core-site.xml`, which is also in `$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/etc/hadoop/`:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://mydns.asuscomm.com:8021</value>
</property>
```

I can successfully view the file on my laptop using

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs:///user/stevenhurwitt/jars/
```

But when I run `spark-submit` using:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster \             
--class com.steven.redditStreaming.dataFrameFromCSVFile \
hdfs:///user/stevenhurwitt/jars/redditStreaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR deploy.ClientEndpoint: Exception from cluster was: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///user/stevenhurwitt/jars/redditStreaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have tried including `hdfs:///mydns.asuscomm.com:8021/user...` but still get the same error.

Comment: _No host_ refers to absence of a hostname between scheme `hdfs://` and path `/user/...`. Your last hdfs uri is almost right, you just have to remove one slash, like this `hdfs://mydns.asuscomm.com:8021/user...`

Comment: thank you, that did the trick! also helped me to realize *why* it uses two slashes vs three in some places

Comment: Great! Glad that helped!